# Android adapter getItemViewType not working properly

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I want the first item of a list to be a picture and the subsequent ones to be comments for it. Obviously both types of items have different layouts. My `getItemViewType` is as follows:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

And my `getView` is

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (position == 0) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            ...
        }
    }
    else {
        if (convertView == null) {
            ....
            convertView.setTag(tag);
        }
        Holder holder = convertView.getTag();
        ...
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

The problem is the recycled views still use the `convertView` from the one inflated at position 0 for the ones on the comments! Since I don't set tags for that `convertView`, `holder` is null. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Note I use an `ArrayAdapter` if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to override [getViewTypeCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount()) and return number of different view type that you have:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not check position.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            ...
        }
    }
    else {
        if (convertView == null) {
            ....
            convertView.setTag(tag);
        }
        Holder holder = convertView.get(tag);
        ...
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
else {
    if (convertView == null || getViewType(position) == 2)
```